# Fabric JS changing src of an object to a url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs

Is it possible to change the `src` attribute of a fabric js object to a url of a CDN?

```
{ version: '4.4.0',
  objects:
   [ { type: 'image',
       version: '4.4.0',
       originX: 'left',
       
       ...

       src:'www.cdn.com',

       crossOrigin: null,
       filters: [] },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the src property by just editing the src prop to CDN url and when you load json it will load the cdn image,

or if you want to change the src in editor then you can use the following:

```
changeImageSrcToCDN(newSrc, imageObject) { //imageObject is the image being replaced
        var url = newSrc;
        var scaleX = imageObject.scaleX;
        var scaleY = imageObject.scaleY;
        var width = imageObject.width;
        var height = imageObject.height;
        var left = imageObject.left;
        var top = imageObject.top;

        imageObject.setSrc(url, (image) => {
            image.left = left;
            image.top = top;
            image.scaleX = scaleX;
            image.scaleY = scaleY;
            image.width = width;
            image.height = height;
            image.setCoords();
            canvas.renderAll();
        }, { width: imageObject.width, height: imageObject.height, crossOrigin: 'anonymous' });
    }
```